# Navigation buttons

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am creating a form in Visual Studio C# and the program has multiple tabs (Home, 2nd tab, ...). On every tab there are different elements and when i click a button for a certain tab the elements for that tab are visible (visibility = true) and the other are hidden...

Now all of that works but now it gets very messy in the editor because all the elements are shown...

How can I hide elements in the editor so that i have only ones for the tab I am working on?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello. Could you provide some more details about what you're trying to do? What kind of form are you creating? Is it WinForms? Could you paste the code that you use to hide/show elements on the tabs?

Comment: Or add a screenshot if it is design-time behavior you have trouble with

Comment: It is a Windows Form Application C# and the line for hiding/showing: element.Visible = True;

Comment: Is it possible to activate events in the designer? so when the button would be pressed the Visible property would change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use a `TabControl`.

It is the very purpose for which TabControl control is made. [Read here what is a TabControl and how to use it in your forms.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983731(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: This is actually what I want - I can change tabs in the designer, but I would like to use different buttons to change tabs...

Comment: Hey, I was on leave. In case you did not find the solution..... you can achieve your required task by setting `SelectedTab` property of `TabControl` control like `tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[1];` or `tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[5];`

Answer (score -3):

Hide the default tabs like this.....
tcMain is a tabControl.

```
    //Hide the Tabs
    tcMain.Appearance = TabAppearance.FlatButtons;
    tcMain.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
    tcMain.ItemSize = new Size(0, 1);
```

and then you can use another control of your choosing to change the active tab.

```
tcMain.SelectedTab = tabPageToChangeTo;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13575529)

Comment: I think I've ansered now.
He wants to use a tab control but have his own button control the tabs.